# How does the statement contradict the proposition?

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem 2.30**

Let $\{(X_\alpha, \mathscr T_\alpha):\alpha \in \Lambda\}$ be an indexed family of topological spaces, and for each $\alpha \in \Lambda,$ let $\mathscr B_\alpha$ be a basis for $\mathscr T_\alpha$. Then the collection $\mathscr B$ of all sets of the form $\prod _{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha$, where $B_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for all but a finite number of members, $\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n$ of $\Lambda$ and $B_{\beta_i}\in \mathscr B_{\beta_i}$ for each $i=1,2,3,..,n,$ is the basis for the product topology on $\prod _{\alpha \in \Lambda}X_\alpha$.

[image]

My Doubt:-
 It is the theorem from the 'Foundation of Topology' by C.W Patty.

(1) By Theorem 2.30, it should be $U_\alpha \in \mathscr B_\alpha$ instead of  $U_\alpha \in \mathscr T_\alpha$. Right?

(2) It should be $\pi_{\beta}(B)=X_\beta$. Right?

(3) Can you please explain the underlined statement?

How does the statement contradict the proposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}_\alpha$ is right. We know that for a local base element $B \in \mathcal{B}$ (there are no $\mathcal{B}_\alpha$ in this direction of the proof at all!) there is a standard-basic open subset that contains $x$ and sits inside $B$; this follows simply from sets of the described form being a base for the topology of the product (which is what 2.30 says when applied to $\mathcal{B}_\alpha = \mathcal{T}_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ e.g.).

(2) says that for each $B$, almost all (all but finitely many) $\beta$ obey $\pi_\beta[B]=X_\beta$ (indeed, the $X_\alpha$ is a typo). So for all $B\in \mathcal{B}$ together we have at most countably many exceptions, so still plenty of such $\beta$ exist.

But then recall how $x$ was chosen: for all indices in $\Gamma$, so also for this $\beta$ with the property

$$\forall B \in \mathcal{B}: \pi_\beta[B]=X_\beta \tag{1}$$

we have a neighbourhood $x_\beta \in  U_\beta \neq X_\beta$. So $x \in \pi_\beta^{-1}[U_\beta]$, which is an open neighbourhood of $x$ so as $\mathcal{B}$ is a local base at $x$, there must be a $B' \in \mathcal{B}$ such that

$$x \in B' \subseteq \pi_\beta^{-1}[U_\beta]$$ but his implies that $$X_\beta = \text{ by (1) } = \pi_\beta[B'] \subseteq U_\beta \neq X_\beta$$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: For (1) instead of writing 'using the theorem 3.20'. I think I can say $B$ is a local basis element. So $B$ is open. so there exists a base element of product topology. right?

Comment: @Mathgeek right, that’s enough.

Comment: While reading the proof, I got one more doubt. Why $\pi_\alpha(B)=X_\alpha$ for all but finite members of $\alpha \in \Lambda$?

Comment: second paragraph, eighth line.

Comment: @Mathgeek $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$ by definition, and  $\prod_{\alpha \in \Lambda} U_\alpha \subseteq B$. Take $\pi_\alpha$ on both sides and we get $U_\alpha \subseteq \pi_\alpha[B]$. So the latter set is $X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$.